# Android: Runtime error when i auto switch facebook activity to twitter activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Runtime error when i auto switch facebook activity to twitter activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    originalProductName = SingletonFacebookInfo.productName;
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);

    myLogoffButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.myQuitBtn);
    myPostToWalloffButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.myPostBtn);
    refreshNewsFeedButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.myRefreshBtn);     
    myET=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.myPostET);

    commentsLV=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.commentsLV);
    itemList=new ArrayList<Wallitem>();


    // start Facebook Login and create a session
    fb_connect();

      **final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // switch to twitter activity
                Intent mInHome = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AuthActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(mInHome);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 120000);**



}//end of onCreate
```

Error Logs:

```
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.facebookpagesample/com.example.facebookpagesample.AuthActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.tmm.android.twitter.appliaction.TwitterApplication
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.tmm.android.twitter.appliaction.TwitterApplication
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at com.example.facebookpagesample.AuthActivity.getConsumerProvider(AuthActivity.java:180)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at com.example.facebookpagesample.AuthActivity.onCreate(AuthActivity.java:49)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
05-08 17:11:26.206: E/AndroidRuntime(5504):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
```

Comment: tell us which is line number 49 in AuthActivity.java..

Comment: @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_oauth);
  
  //check for saved log in details..
  checkForSavedLogin();

  //set consumer and provider on teh Application service
  getConsumerProvider();
  
  //Define login button and listener
  buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonLogin);
  buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
   public void onClick(View v) {
    askOAuth();
   }
  });
 }

Comment: your ButtonLogin is button or imagebutton???

Comment: it's a button. i've a facebook project and twitter project.Both are working fine.i've also integrated facebook and twitter. Now the problem is i want to auto switch from facebook activity to twitter activity back and forth.

Comment: i think the problem lies in my code of switching my activity. I wonder is it the right way to do it

Comment: error is: java.lang.ClassCastException mean you are casting wrong class..